# When I run my code, it opens the window but doesn't show the image

Tags: python, image, pygame

```
 display = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 200))
 pygame.display.set_caption("Decision Bar Window")
 decisionBarImage = pygame.image.load('D:/Adriel/Documents/Python stuff/Games/Basic python game/Images/decision_bar.png')
 display.blit(decisionBarImage, (250,100))
 pygame.display.flip
```

When I run my code, it opens the window but doesn't show the image

Comment: Where are you running your code from? Where is the file located?

Comment: I have edited my code to include the whole directory of decision_bar.png and it still doesn't work

Comment: i recommend to add an `r` to your string like `r'D:\...'`

Comment: I believe the problem could be that you've used backslashes, which act as escape characters. Try forward slashes instead. @luigigi 's method of treating it as a raw string would also work

Comment: I've added the exact directory of decision_bar.png and now it opens the window but doesn't show the image

Comment: Hmmmm, I'll try it

Comment: I've added forward slashed and now it opens the window but doesn't show the image.

Comment: do I use `r` as well as forward slashes?

Comment: Is this all of your code? There is no code that paints the image on the screen.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to a completely different question, as it makes all the answers no longer valid. If you have a new question, then create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The file might not be in your working directory. If not, you need to specify the exact path to the file, either absolute ('/users/...') or relative ('./...').

Comment: hmmm, I've added the exact directory of decision_bar.png and now it opens the window but doesn't show the image

Answer (score 0):

1. Your filepath has backslashes, so you either need to change the path to `r'D:\PATH\TO\FILE'`, so Python treats it as a raw string literal, instead of using backslashes as escape characters.
2. You're not actually placing the image onscreen, only loading it into pygame. Look [here](https://pythonprogramming.net/displaying-images-pygame/) for an example. The important part is

```py
carImg = pygame.image.load('racecar.png')
display = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 200))
def car(x,y):
     display.blit(carImg, (x,y))
```

As a final note, I'd put `pygame.display` into its own variable to make it more readable.

Comment: Okay I’ll do that once I have access to my laptop. I’m currently eating dinner.

Comment: It threw an error: `AttributeError: module 'pygame.display' has no attribute 'blit'`

Comment: @ChronicleEdge Updated to assign display to variable, try this

Comment: I did it (see above) and now it opens the window but doesn't show the image